# Create-react-app not working at "npm start" even though correct npm/node version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

1. I am learning react following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0). I got an error about not having a start script which, using my text editor I added to the package.json file. Now I don't really know how to fix what my new error is.
2. Updated my package-json file, uninstalled and reinstalled create-react-app, made new react-app folder, read through stack overflow. start it manually with "npx react-scripts start".
3. My npm -v (6.7.0) and node -v (12.16.0)

   File directory tree of react-app

   - node_modules

     - list of folders that were added upon making folder using create-react-app
   - public

     - favicon.ico
     - index.html
     - manifest.json
   - src

     - index.js
   - .gitignore
   - package.json
   - package-lock.json
   - README.md

Error:

```
circulating@CLAPP-T460-22 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/react-app (master)
$ npm start

> react-app@1.1.0 start C:\Users\circulating\Desktop\react-app
> react-scripts start


i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.16/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\circulating\Desktop\re                                                                                                                act-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app@1.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@1.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                                                ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\circulating\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-07T01_                                                                                                                12_36_919Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Add C:\Windows\System32 to the global PATH environment variable.

or

reinstall your npm with a different react script version. Simply go to your folder in command and reinstall like this:
    npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
    npm start